Firebase Cloud Messaging sending push notification but always throws error
I have a cloud function that takes an fcmToken and sends a push notification to the right device.
The .then is triggered and the console log inside as well, but the Success html never shows. Instead, it always goes to the catch and shows the Failure html with an empty error.
Where am I going wrong?
Function code:
const {onRequest} = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const serviceAccount = require("./serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

exports.sendNotification = onRequest((request, response) => {
  const token = request.params[0].replace("/", "");
  const registrationToken = token;

  console.log("Token: " + token);

   const message = {
     notification: {
       title: "Hello",
       body: "body text...",
     },
     token: registrationToken,
   };

  admin.messaging().send(payload)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("Successfully sent message:", JSON.stringify(response));
        response.send(`<h1>Success</h1>`);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorString = JSON.stringify(error);
        console.log("Error sending message:", errorString);
        response.send(`<h1>Failure: ${errorString}</h1>`);
      });
});


It seems that your response isn't JSON.stringify'able. Perhaps try {  .... JSON.stringify(response) .... } catch ((error) => { console.log(error); }?

Thanks Daz, you were right. Also, I used "response" twice so when I hit send() it was referring to the wrong one.
